# Помогите понять различия

Tags: c++

У меня есть два класса:

```
class Dog {
public:
   Dog(string name) {
     this->name = name;
}
   void bark() {
        cout << name << ": Woof!" << endl;
}
private:
    string name;
};
```

(точно такой же класс Cat, но я его не добавил, попросту не зачем)

В книге мне рекомендуют вызывать методы классов вот так:

```
Dog Tosha("Tosha");
Dog *pTosha = &Tosha;
pTosha->bark();
```

Но зачем так делать, если можно просто сделать так:

```
Dog Tosha("Tosha");
Tosha.bark();
```

Обьясните, я еще на стадии учения.

Comment: *"Но зачем так делать"* Нет смысла так делать, разве что для демонстрации указателей.

Comment: Второй (ваш) вариант лучше. Можно полный текст? Вероятно, вы выдернули из контекста потеряв суть.

Comment: Вообще, там тема "Виртуальные функции \ наследование \ полиморфизм" (в книге). Но этот код я написал сам, и сделал два варианта. Может быть это просто ивправду демонстрация указателей.

Comment: Там, вероятно, демонстрировали другое. Допустим у вас Dog наследник Animal `Dog : Animal {...}`. Тогда можно писать `Animal *pTosha = &Tosha;` дальше эту ссылку передавать в функции, которые хотят принять `Animal*` и которым плевать на то, кого, кота или собаку, эта ссылка на самом деле указывает. И у `pTosha` можно будет вызывать методы Animal.

Comment: Да, там именно такой код был, спасибо, а то не понимал что он делает, я думал это просто вариант такого написания.